# do you have to go to the air force to be a commercial pilot

Tags: aircraft-systems

do you have to go to the air force to be a commercial pilot

Comment: No, you do not.

Comment: Which country are you asking about?

Comment: Please don't open new accounts to repeat a question.  It won't work here.  Instead, edit your existing question or ask for clarification on the answers given.